# Issue while adding action to UIButton in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3

I am Creating a `UIButton` programatically in `swift 3`.

But I am unable to add Action to it.

```
     //Adding BUtton
    let btn = UIButton()

    btn.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)

    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.printname()), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(btn)

    //Method to be called
    func printname()
    {
        print("button pressed")
    }
```

What I am doing wrong in above code?

**EDIT**

Now I am using this Code:

```
     btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.printname(sender:)), for:.touchUpInside)


      func printname(sender: UIButton)
      {
         print("button pressed")
      }

      When I select Button this method is never called.
```

Comment: Try this btn.addTarget(self,action:#selector(Viewcontrollername.printname),for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

Comment: @matt getting this error now : `Argument of ‘#selecotr’ cannot refer to global function ‘printname()’`

Answer (score 0):

```
//Adding BUtton
let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100))
btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
btn.setTitle("Test Button", forState: .Normal)
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(printname), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

self.view.addSubview(btn)

//button action
func printname (){
  print("button pressed")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `()` to the end of a method when you are passing that method as a selector! This is because `()` is used to specify the arguments when you are *calling* the method. But you don't want to call the method, do you? So remove the `()`!

```
 //Adding BUtton
let btn = UIButton()

btn.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)

// () removed!
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.printname), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

self.view.addSubview(btn)

//Method to be called
func printname()
{
    print("button pressed")
}
```

This is the same as passing a closure to a method:

```
doStuff(withClosure: myMethod)

func myMethod() {
    // ...
}
```

This holds true no matter how many arguments there are in the method passed in.

EDIT: I just saw that your `printname` method seems to be inside another method. If this is true, please move it to the class level! Also, you need to add a `sender` argument to `printname`:

```
func printname(sender: UIButton) {
    // ...
}
```